# How to install bootstrap datepicker with JSPM

Tags: jspm

Today I wanted to install https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker with jspm for my Aurelia project. So I did this

```
jspm install -y npm:bootstrap-datepicker
```

It didn't report any errors back, however the result was only a single .js file, when I checked in jspm_packages after the install. The folders and css files were missing.

I've asked in jspm gitter and reported it in github, it doesn't look however, like there a lot of activity or feedback in there.

For example I found this old pull ( https://github.com/jspm/registry/pull/204 ) which is still open, so I guess it is not likely that this will be fixed anytime soon.

So I'd be very interested in a an alternative workaround, if anyone would happen to know how to do such a thing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other files should in the `bootstrap-datepicker@1.5.0` folder.

Check the path at `jspm_packages/npm/bootstrap-datepicker@1.5.0` again.

Comment: *WHAT? Somehow this worked just now. Couldn't find the folder all day yesterday. Thanks anyways, because of your comment I went back and installed it  once again, and now it works heh. :D